# Angular7 button not disabled when the form is initialized

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to disable a button when the form is not filled. Everything works fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE11 the button is still enabled. That is the code:

```
<div class="col-12">
     <app-button label="login.login" (click)="save()" [disabled]="(!f.dirty || f.invalid) ? 'disable' : null"></app-button>
     <div class="pt-3 text-right">
      <a [routerLink]="['/login']" class="pt-5">{{"login.changepassword" | translate}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The odd thing is that if I make a minimal change (for example, change the label) in the html generated through the browser inspector (F12), it works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't `disabled` need to be true or false? Have you tried replacing `null` with `false`?

Comment: Do you enable your app to work with ie ? ( base on angular tutorial)

Comment: @WillAlexander, I already tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @AliMaleki, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the form on the script.
like this.

```
 loginForm: FormGroup;    
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm= this.formBuilder.group({
    uname: ["",{validators.required}],
}
```

and then bind it in the html.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" >
<input type="text" name="uname" formControlName="uname"/>
<app-button (click)="save()" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid"></app-button>
</form>
```

Or you could use ngModel make sure it is boolean though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow approach by adding an @Input decorator to detect when the button must be disabled.

**Component app-buton.component.ts**

```
selector:['app-button'],
templeateUrl: ['./app-buton.component.html']
....
Class ButtonComponent {
  @Input isDisabled: booelan
}
```

**Component app-buton.component.html**

```
<button  [disabled]="isDisabled">
```

Then now where the app buton component is implemented you need to do the following code:

```
<app-button [isDisabled]="(!f.dirty || !f.valid)"> </app-button>
```

Comment: @dellasavia here